# Why do I sometimes get the warning "Expected 'collections.Iterable', got 'WebElement' instead"?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using Selenium's `find_element(By.XPATH, "//tag[@class='classname']"`, when I try to iterate over elements of certain classes, I sometimes get this warning by Pycharm : "*Expected 'collections.Iterable', got 'WebElement' instead*". I don't understand why it would iterate over some classes with no problem and others not. Could it have something to do with the different tags?

In the code bellow, `issues_available` is highlighted in green and displays the warning mentioned above.

**code:**

```
issues_available = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='issue ember-view']")
    currently_clicked_issue = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "div[@class='issue active-override ember-view']")
    issues_list = []
    for issue in issues_available:

        issue_vol_number = issue.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='label']").text
///
```

Comment: Can you show us the code which is causing this issue ?

Comment: there is a difference between find_element and find_element**s**

Comment: @cruisepandey code added

Comment: @double_wizz :  see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write this

```
issues_available = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='issue ember-view']")
```

Now `issues_available`  is a single web element.

and It makes no sense to iterate a single web element.

Instead, you should use :

```
find_elements
```

which will return a list of web elements.

So, your effective code will be :

```
issues_available = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='issue ember-view']")
currently_clicked_issue = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "div[@class='issue active-override ember-view']")
issues_list = []
for issue in issues_available:
    issue_vol_number = issue.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='label']").text
```